request.FILES.get is returning None
I was developing my website, just when I realized that the update_supplier view stopped working correctly. In this view I update the name and the image. For some reason it is only getting the name and not the image from the request. When I try to print request.FILES it returns a empty multidictionary.
<MultiValueDict: {}>
This is my form:
{% for supplier in all_suppliers %}
    <div class="modal fade" id="staticSupplierUpdate{{ supplier.id }}" data-bs-backdrop="static"
         data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
         aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Editar Fornecedor</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="update_supplier_form" method="post" action="{% url 'update-supplier' supplier.id %}"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label_form_create_project d-flex text-left"
                       for="update_supplier_name{{ supplier.id }}">Nome:</label>
                <input type="text" id="update_supplier_name{{ supplier.id }}" name="update_supplier_name"
                       value="{{ supplier.name_supplier }}" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label_form_create_project d-flex text-left" for="update_supplier_image{{ supplier.pk }}">Imagem
                  do
                  fornecedor:</label>
                <div class="custom-file">
                  <input type="file" id="update_supplier_image{{ supplier.pk }}" class="custom-file-input"
                         name="update_supplier_image"
                         accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"
                         onchange="previewImageSupplierUpdate(this, '{{ supplier.pk }}')">
                  <label class="custom-file-label custom-file-label-update-supplier"
                         for="update_supplier_image{{ supplier.pk }}">Escolha uma imagem</label>
                </div>
                <img id="imagePreview{{ supplier.pk }}" src="{{ supplier.image_supplier.url }}" alt="Image Preview"
                     style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px; margin-top: 10px; ">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save_project">Salvar</button>
            </form>
            <form id="deleteSupplierForm" action="{% url 'delete-supplier' 0 %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="hidden" id="deleteSupplierId" name="delete_supplier_id" value="">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary delete_product mt-3"
                      onclick="return confirmDeleteSupplier({{ supplier.id }})">Eliminar
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

This is my view:
def update_supplier(request, supplier_id):
    supplier = get_object_or_404(Supplier, id=supplier_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        updated_supplier_name = request.POST.get('update_supplier_name')
        updated_supplier_image = request.FILES.get('update_supplier_image')
        if updated_supplier_image:
            supplier.image_supplier = updated_supplier_image
        supplier.name_supplier = updated_supplier_name
        supplier.save()
        return JsonResponse({'success': 'Informações atualizadas com sucesso'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Volte a preencher os campos.'})

I tried looking the answer in chatGPT and in stackOverflow, but couldn't find it. The only thing they said is that I need to have a form with enctype="multipart/form-data" which I already have.

Is this a case of "it was working before but now it just ain’t working again"?
